# Magento Custom Newsletter Subscription

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

I want to create a custom newsletter subscription using Magento 1.9.1.0.

Currently, I have one newsletter subscription that captures emails and stores it in **Newsletter -> Newsletter Subscribers**.

I want to create another one that stores it in the same location. This time, when the users subscribe on the new one, it will popup a modal.

Is this possible or is there any other way around for this? Thank you.

EDIT:
If possible, is it possible to execute/submit the subscription via Ajax? I think this would solve my problem but I don't know how to write it in Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by using this code from [here](http://twincreations.co.uk/using-magentos-built-in-ajax-submit-with-validation/).

I tweaked the code to fit my current code structure. First, my form has an ID of `newsletter-ajax`.

Here's what I did with the JavaScript Ajax Code:

1. Declare this variables

   `var formId = 'newsletter-ajax'; 
   var myForm = new VarienForm(formId, true); 
   var postUrl = "/newsletter/subscriber/new";`
2. Create the ajax function

   `function doAjax() {
       if (myForm.validator.validate()) {
           new Ajax.Updater(
               { success:'formSuccess' }, postUrl, {
                   method:'post',
                   asynchronous:true,
                   evalScripts:false,
                   onComplete:function(request, json) {
                       Element.hide(formId);
                       Element.show('formSuccess');
                   },
                   onLoading:function(request, json){
                       Element.show('formLoader');
                   },
                   parameters: $(formId).serialize(true),
               }
           );
       }
   }`
3. Create the event observer

   `new Event.observe(formId, 'submit', function(e){
       e.stop();
       doAjax();
   });`

Do note that these codes should be inside a `<script>` tag (pretty sure everyone knows this).

Read more about how I did it at twincreations from the link above.